# How can I replace a Fragment from within onTouch() of another Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, ontouch

I need to display a `Fragment` when the user touches the `TextView` of another `Fragment`. Here's what I have:

```
public class FindPeopleHelpFragment extends Fragment {

    public FindPeopleHelpFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_people_help, container, false);

        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.find_people_help);

        TextView welcome_home = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.find_people_help);
        welcome_home.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent evt) {
                if (evt.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    EditProfileFragment editProfileFragment = new EditProfileFragment();
                    FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, editProfileFragment, editProfileFragment.getTag()).commit();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;
    }
}
```

The issue is that `onTouch()` returns a `boolean`, but when replacing the `Fragment`, I need to return a `View`. Otherwise I get the following.

```
 10-05 15:00:51.057 25152-25152/wegrok.chiaramail.com E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: wegrok.chiaramail.com, PID: 25152
                                                                       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0f00b1 (wegrok.chiaramail.com:id/fragment_container) for fragment FindPeopleHelpFragment{c052157 #1 id=0x7f0f00b1}
```

Anyone know how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make these `Fragment` transactions from your `Activity`. The `Activity` that hosted the `Fragment` should have a public function for handling the fragment switching so that when the `TextView` of your `Fragment1` is clicked, the public method of the `Activity` will be called to make the `Fragment` switch.

So you might consider having an `Activity` like this.

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

        // The Fragment 1 will be loaded by default
        switchToFragment1();
    }

    public void switchToFragment1() {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Fragment1()).commit();
    }

    public void switchToFragment2() {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Fragment2()).commit();
    }
}
```

Now from your `Fragment1`, you need to implement an onClick listener in to the `TextView`, so that when the `TextView` is clicked, `Fragment1` switches to `Fragment2`.

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ((YourActivity) getActivity()).switchToFragment2();
    }
});)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Glad to know that helped.